# Can someone identify this video/power connector?

Tags: pcb, connector

I bought a cheap peephole camera that comes with a viewing tablet. [Something like this.](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000927681224.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.610b42ebWvLEIH&algo_pvid=904d9e8d-d89a-417c-95ed-e0deaec0b7a4&aem_p4p_detail=202110130747291649517314928600034590931&algo_exp_id=904d9e8d-d89a-417c-95ed-e0deaec0b7a4-9&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2210000011261858064%22%7D)

The tablet has no ability to interface with any other system (no Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, USB). It is a simple PCB with a cheap Chinese chip.

The camera itself is decent. My plan is to somehow connect it to a Raspberry Pi Zero and use it to stream the video over network. (Software developer here, that part is not a problem.)

Can you tell me which type of connector this is? Is there any reasonably convenient way to connect this to a Raspberry Pi?

EDIT: [This seems to be the chip manufacturer](http://www.zh-jieli.com/)

EDIT: I'm adding two pictures here:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for starting the conversation but its more like a PCB or motherboard connector. I dont think its analog.

Comment: Added two images of my own

Comment: @brhans you have to look down towards the bottom of the product description, not in the photos at the top. It's some kind of a flat flex, but the camera isn't meant to be used separately from their display unit, so they don't tell you what it is. There's no real way to guess, though it could be CSI or USB.

Comment: Give us a scope image of the video signal and we'll be able to give you better advice.

Comment: Looks like a Hirose high speed connector. The exact type will be downto the pitch and other mechanical dimension

Comment: @Hearth Not sure what you mean. Like a picture of the screen displaying video from the camera?

Comment: No, a picture of an oscilloscope showing what the signal on the line looks like.

Comment: @Hearth Beyond my means currently. But if there's no other way, I'll get it.

Comment: Without knowing what the signal looks like, we can't tell you if it can be interfaced to an rpi or not. We need to know what format the signal is.

Comment: @isaric You would have to know which pin is for what. Maybe if you knew what chip was being used at one end of the connection someone would know. It appears to be a 480*320 sensor, so maybe there is some upscaling going on. Of course, the easy way would be to aim a Raspberry Pi camera at the screen...

Comment: @AndrewMorton that is what I'm trying to avoid doing. How about grabing the video signal that the PCB outputs to its screen? The connector looks similar to the rpi camera connector.

Comment: http://www.zh-jieli.com/ - the chip manufacturer

Comment: Can you use a microscope or magnifying glass to see if there are any markings on the connectors?  JST is a common manufacturer of such small connectors; if you can find some characters written on it, perhaps it is that JST part series.

Comment: Looks like too many pins for MIPI CSI. Might be the old MIPI C**P**I standard ...

Comment: @Hearth or anyone else, could you specify the type of osciloscope I should use to get the appropriate image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a board to board connector with one side mounted on a flex PCB. There are loads of variants, perhaps someone can find the exact one.

But even if you do find out what the connector itself is, it probablly won't help you much. As a general rule connector manufacturers just make connectors, they don't specify the electrical interfaces used over them. There are a handful of connectors designed specifically for some particular interface standard but that is the exception not the rule.

I strongly suspect that the connector carries the raw interface to the camera sensor. Unfortunately raw camera interfaces aren't very standardised, some camera sensors use standard interfaces like MIPI CSI for the actual image data but even when they do they need sensor-specific configuration before they will produce image data.

Comment: so, abandon all hope?

Comment: If you aren't up for a destructive teardown of the camera itself to figure out what the sensor is, pouring over the darker corners of the internet for a leaked datasheet for the sensor, manually belling out the cable to figure out which pin is which and then somehow hacking up something to drive it probablly yes.

Comment: ok, fair enough. I'll let it stew for another day before I confirm the answer, if that's ok with you.